# How can I set zsh to use physical paths?

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, pwd

In bash, I can put `set -P` in my `.bashrc`, and to use absolute paths. That is, if I change to a directory through a symbolic link, and then use `cd ..`, it takes me to that directory's canonical parent, not the directory containing the symbolic link.

**How can I configure zsh to always use absolute paths?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From `zshoptions(1)`

> ```
>    CHASE_LINKS (-w)
>           Resolve symbolic links to their true values when changing direc-
>           tory.  This also has the effect of CHASE_DOTS, i.e. a `..'  path
>           segment  will  be  treated  as referring to the physical parent,
>           even if the preceding path segment is a symbolic link.
> ```

So you would `setopt CHASE_LINKS` somewhere in your `.zshrc`. There are also flags to `cd` that will vary how `cd` behaves.

> ```
>           If  the -s option is specified, cd refuses to change the current
>           directory if the given pathname contains symlinks.   If  the  -P
>           option is given or the CHASE_LINKS option is set, symbolic links
>           are resolved to their true values.  If the -L  option  is  given
>           symbolic  links are retained in the directory (and not resolved)
>           regardless of the state of the CHASE_LINKS option.
> ```